# Admob Interstitial Ad

Tags: android, admob

I want to use Interstitial ad in my Android app. But I want it to appear after every 10 minutes because in my app there is no pause or level. Once a user login will keep watching it for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use handlers . At int delay=15000 calculate and give delay of 10 min

```
  Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 15000; //15 seconds
Runnable runnable;
@Override
protected void onStart() {
 //start handler as activity become visible

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //do something
      // Show your Admob Ad here and Refetch the ad else it wont be shown second time

    if (admnbInterstetial.isLoaded()) {
        admnbInterstetial.show();
    }
   AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            admnbInterstetial.loadAd(adRequest1);


            runnable=this;

            h.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }, delay);

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    h.removeCallbacks(runnable); //stop handler when activity not visible
    super.onPause();
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your support will surely try this. But I have read somewhere if I do it Google can suspend my admob account. Is true?

Comment: sorry i dont know about that for sure, if above answer  worked for you please acccept the answer